# Best practice for User Control Data Binding - How to achieve this?

Tags: .net, winforms, data-binding, ado.net, user-controls

I've got an User Control with TextBoxes, Labels, ... . Now I would like to get the same Data Binding Features like I would place the Controls directly on the Form. I tried with an extra Binding Source and Error Provider in the User Control and I tried to make the Properties of my Controls available as an property.

Nothing worked. So there have to be an solution to get this done. So how?

Comment: Can you provide a small code sample (or more specifics) of what bindings you are trying to produce? Also C# or vb.net code example  preference?

Comment: I'll try:
I've got a TabControl with 3 TabPages. These 3 TabPages have 3 Addresses (Delivery, Invoice, Default). Now I've got a AddressUserControl and add this UserControl on the TabPages. My DataBinding on the main Form has a POCO with DeliveryAddress, InvoiceAddress and DefaultAddress. So how can I achieve a good Data Binding with ErrorProvider? The ErrorProvider is on the main form, too.

Comment: A question about the POCO: I don't understand whether the DeliveryAddress, InvoiceAddress and DefaultAddress properties are strings or POCOs (with properties like street, zip code and so on). Could you write some (pseudo) code that show how they are defined?

Answer (score 2):

I've realized a sample at https://github.com/edymtt/usercontrolwithdatabinding to illustrate some data binding scenarios that may apply to your question. In particular I've addressed two scenarios:

1. Realization of an `UserControl` to edit a basic property (string, integer, ...);
2. Realization of an `UserControl` to edit a property of a complex type (such as an `Address` POCO);

### Realization of an `UserControl` to edit a basic property

In this case it suffices to expose the relevant property of an underlying control (for example the `Text` property of a `TextBox`) and to raise an appropriate event when this changes (continuing the example, handle the `TextChanged` event of the `TextBox` and raise a new `TextChanged` event, see [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz45s2bh.aspx) at the section "Change Notification for Custom Controls).

The `ErrorProvider` in the form (where you have the binding source) can handle this kind of UserControl without problem

### Realization of an `UserControl` to edit a property of a complex type

This case is not much complex than the previous:

- you need to put a `BindingSource` and an `Error Provider` in the usercontrol to handle the POCO you need;
- next you need expose a property to receive the bound object and assign it at runtime.

I hope that the sample is clear enough to understand how the binding works.